# Why is orthogonal projection matrix has property that $P=P^T$

Tags: orthogonal-matrices

I know that definition of orthogonal projection matrix is 
its range and null space are orthogonal.

And, definition of projection matrix is $P=P^2$

Then, I understand that if $P$ is $n\times n$ projection matrix.
$P=P^T \Rightarrow P$ is orthogonal projection matrix(using fundamental theorem of linear algebra)

Then, how could I proof that 
$P$ is orthogonal projection matrix $\Rightarrow P=P^T$

Can I solve it with using SVD?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305296/can-a-non-symmetric-projection-matrix-exist) might be helpful.

Comment: Use orthogonality of Px and y-Py as well as orthogonality of Py and x-Px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any projection $P$, the kernel of $P$ is the image of $I-P$, and
$\ker P \oplus \Im P = V$. So you only need to show that if these two spaces are orthogonal, then $P$ is self adjoint. We can directly check:
$$\langle Px, y\rangle = \langle Px, (I-P)y + Py\rangle = \langle Px, Py \rangle, $$
and similarly $\langle x, Py \rangle = \langle Px, Py \rangle $, so we have equality.

Comment: How do you conclude the self-adjointness from this equality? (I know this might be obvious if one knows the basics, but I don't.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint